# How to login as a domain user after using realm join domain

Tags: active-directory, domain

I have made my rhel 8 join Windows Active Directory and it is also visible from the server end. But now how do I login as a user of that domain?

Comment: Have you tried the obvious `DOMAIN\user` or `user@dom.ain`? If so please [edit] your question to say so - and explain what happened.

Comment: Yes I did and it dint work. My workplace is trying to move from Windows to Linux. Like how in windows system you can use anyone's station and log in as a different user using Domain\user we want to do it in RHEL 8.

so I used Rhel8's realmd and added it to my office's Domain.

now I log out and try to login as a different user(in the domain)
(my process is log-out then click not listed)
Using user name as DOMAIN\user
and using its password
I am getting an error  "Sorry That din't work. Please try again"

Comment: So please [edit] your question to include this information. Make it easy for us to help you!